# Einstein Voice?

Tags: einstein

So I am trying to play around with Einstein voice on mobile. I have added Einstein Assistant and Einstein Insights however I can't get the features to even show up in app. I am adding it via the Mobile Quick Start Wizard but it never appears in the app. Am I missing something?

This is in a playground org btw.